# File change event not being fired

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple file input and I'm using some javascript to handle its change event. The problem is, if I select one file and then select another file with the same name then the change even isn't fired.

Is there some other event I can use. My only other idea (seeing as you can't clear the file input value with JavaScript) is to remove the element from them DOM and create a new one once the form is submitted.

Comment: What have you tried? Works fine with a simple `.onchange` handler in FF. Is the problem happening in one browser or many?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery to bind it with

```
$('#yourIdOfInputFile').bind('change',function() { 
    //here goes your code
});
```

then its triggered - always!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening in IE & Crome, not Firefox. When file is the same, the change event is not firing. 
I suggest you creating a new input everytime file changes. Since this workaround simply replace the `input` with newly empty input, so the second time file is selected, no matter what the file is, `change` event will be fired.

http://browser.colla.me/show/file_input_triggers_no_change_event_if_file_names_are_the_same